# Class 'Album\Controller\AlbumController' not found

Tags: zend-framework2

When i try to start album application an error message appears:

> Fatal error: Class 'Album\Controller\AlbumController' not found in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\ZendSkeletonApplication\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\ServiceManager\AbstractPluginManager.php
>   on line 170

This is my module.config.php file code

```
<?php
return array(
    'controllers' => array(
        'invokables' => array(
            'Album\Controller\Album' => 'Album\Controller\AlbumController',
        ),
    ),

    // Added to make router
    'router' => array(
        'routes' => array(
            'album' => array(
                'type' => 'segment',
                'options' => array(
                    'route' => '/album[/][:action][/:id]',
                    'constraints' => array(
                        'action' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                        'id' => '[0-9]+'
                    ),
                    'defaults' => array(
                        'controller' => 'Album\Controller\Album',
                        'action' => 'index',
                    ),
                ),
            ),
        ),
    ),

    'view_manager' => array(
        'template_path_stack' => array(
            'album' => __DIR__ . '/../view',
        ),
    ),
);
```

And this is AlbumController.php file code:

```
<?php

namespace Album\Controller;

use Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController;
use Zend\View\Model\ViewModel;

class AlbumController extends AbstractActionController {

    protected $albumTable;

    public function indexAction() {
        return new ViewModel(array(
            'album' => $this->getAlbumTable()->fetchAll(),
        ));
    }

    public function addAction() {

    }

    public function editAction() {

    }

    public function deleteAction() {

    }

    public function getAlbumTable () {
        if (!$this->albumTable) {
            $sm = $this->getServiceLocator();
            $this->albumTable = $sm->get('Album\Model\AlbumTable');
        }
        return $this->albumTable;
    }

}
```

Comment: Module classes getConfig() function and getAutoloaderConfig() function, as well as checking all your paths

Answer (score 1):

i see you are just getting started, so i would refer to this code by *Martin Shwalbe* and find out if you have any typo. If everything looks good, then you probably have issue in the way you are accessing it.

https://github.com/Hounddog/Album

hope this helps...